# Rails getting "can't be blank" error even though the field is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm basically validating `user` presence and I've included that as a `hidden_field :user, value: current_user.id` and when I view source, the `id` is there and when I check `POST` data, it's also there. So what could be the cause of this misvalidation?

Answer (score 0):

using the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

and you problems

when your install a device gem using a 
in your controller:

```
class OneController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def action

  end
end
```

and when enter a one controller if you no have a current_user automatic devise return to go sign_in action

is very very easy!

regards